# Conexão com Sqlite retorna Unsupported driver [C]

Tags: laravel, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou tentando usar Sqlite em um projeto porém ao realizar qualquer comando com o Sqlite retorna:

> Unsupported driver [C].

essa é minha configuração no **database.php**

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => true,
    ],
```

Comment: Ativou no `php.ini` a extensão do sqlite?

Comment: Sim eu ativei o sqlite no php.ini

Comment: Ativo o sqlite com PDO ou sem PDO?

Comment: eu ativei os dois

Comment: Reiniciou o Apache?

Comment: eu uso php artisan serve direto. não uso apache

Answer (score 0):

Solucionei. O problema é que se o campo database estiver com o database_path('database.sqlite') o campo url deve estar vazio.